# Error al hacer referencia a label C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Buenas. Primero que todo agradezco la ayuda. 
El problema es el siguiente:
Estoy trabajando en un proyecto de C# , exactamente de WPF , el problema es que cuando intento hacer referencia de un label para cambiar su contendido (debido a que la propiedad en los label en WPF es Content , en Windows Form es Text), extrañamente el VisualStudio(Community2017) el intelisense no me ayuda con la referencia . Por lo cual cual llamo al label por el nombre que fue llamado , me salta el error de que no aparece en el contexto. Pueden hecharme una mano con esto? La verdad soy nuevo en C# y es primera vez que me pasa. Aparte e trabajado en otros proyectos de WindowsForms y no a pasado esto. Quiza este haciendo algo mal.
[image: ssss]

esa es donde esta el nombre del label
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

No es al 100 una solución pero es una forma que facilita mucho la vida, es asignar y leer los valores del XAML por binding

**Codigo CS**

```
private string _etiqueta1;
public String Etiqueta1
{
    get { return _etiqueta1; }
    set
    {
      _etiqueta1= value;
     NotifyPropertyChanged();
  }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<Label Name="lblEtiqueta" Content="{Binding Path=Etiqueta}"/>
```

Comment: @Bryon El problema de esto es que quiero dar el valor de el label durante la ejecucion de programa . Es decir , cambiara constantemente. Alguna otra idea?

Answer (score 0):

comprueba que en el XAML la etiqueta tiene nombre,
en tu caso debería ser así

```
<Label x:Name="labelAssistantSays" />
```